# Split a pdf attribute string on two lines

Tags: pdftex, split, metadata

I have the following:

```
\usepackage[pdftex,
            pdfauthor={Name Surname},
            pdftitle={Title of my document},
            pdfkeywords={A very long string consisting of several words},
            pdfproducer={Producer},
           ]{hyperref}
```

After the pdf is created, when hovering the mouse over the file name, I would like the pdfkeywords content be displayed on two lines. Something like:

A very long string

consisting of several words

Is it possible to do that? I looked around a bit, but found no working solution.

(Actually, I achieved my goal by hacking the pdf file, but this is definitely not what I look for...)

Thanks for any help.

@Ulrike Fischer - in response to your comment: I just opened the pdf with a binary editor and replaced a blank character with a LF character.

Comment: and what hacked you into the pdf?

Answer (score 1):

Here, I just inserted a `^^J` (linefeed) into the `pdfkeywords` field and it showed up with the linefeed in the document properties as such.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,
            pdfauthor={Name Surname},
            pdftitle={Title of my document},
            pdfkeywords={A very long string^^J consisting of several words},
            pdfproducer={Producer},
           ]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
xxx

\end{document}
```

[image]